# C# foreach loop not picking up string

Tags: c#, string, foreach

I have a 'foreach' loop iterating a List but it won't pick up one of the string values for some reason. The string in question is:

`<p>@extractedCaptions[10]</p>` to provide exact string = `"Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo."`.

So I have a `foreach` loop, one of which:

```
}
else if (cap == "Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo.")
{
```

Which it won't pick up. Does anyone know what could be causing this? All other strings are picked up fine.

EDIT - full code

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@using Umbraco.Forms.Core
@using Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage
@using Voice.BL.Extensions
@using Voice.BL.Helpers
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

@{
    Layout = "AdminMaster.cshtml";

    var currentMemberCollaborationGroup = MemberHelper.GetCurrentMemberCollaborationGroup();
    if (currentMemberCollaborationGroup == null)
    {
        var loginNode = VNHelper.GetLoginNode();
        Response.Redirect(loginNode.Url() + "?returnUrl=" + Url.Encode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery), true);
        return;
    }

    var opportunityId = Request.QueryString["opId"].NullSafeToInt();
    var record = FeedbackHelper.GetFeedbackRecordFromOpportunityId(opportunityId);
    var feedbackFormUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, "?altTemplate=OpportunityFeedbackForm&opportunityId=" + opportunityId);

    var opportunity = Umbraco.TypedContent(opportunityId);

    if (opportunity.GetPropertyValue<int>("collaborationGroup") != currentMemberCollaborationGroup.Id)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/dashboard/opportunities/");
    }
}


<section class="c-section">
    @Html.Partial("CollaboratorActivityMenu", Voice.BL.Enums.CollaboratorActivityMenuSelection.Opportunities)
    <div class="o-container">
        <h1>@opportunity.Name</h1>
        @Html.Partial("CollaboratorOpportunityMenu", Model)
    </div>

    <div class="o-container">
        <div class="o-row">
            <div class="o-col o-col--auto@md">
                <h2>Feedback</h2>
            </div>

            @if (record != null)
            {
                <div class="o-col--auto@md u-text-right">
                    @Html.Partial("FeedbackProcess", new ViewDataDictionary { { "OpportunityId", opportunityId } })
                </div>
            }
        </div>

        @if (record != null)
        {
            var extractedFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            var newOrderFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            var extractedCaptions = new List<string>();
            foreach (var field in record.RecordFields)
            {
                var extractValue = field.Value.ValuesAsString().NullSafeToString();
                var extractType = CGHelper.CleanString(field.Value.Field.FieldType.Name).ToLower();
                var extractCaption = field.Value.Field.Caption;
                extractedFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(extractType, extractValue));
                extractedCaptions.Add(extractCaption);
            }

            var count = 0;
            foreach (var cap in extractedCaptions.ToList())
            {
                if (cap == "Opportunity ID")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(0, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Name")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(1, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Project/Study Title")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(2, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Project/Study Overview")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(3, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "How were Voice members involved?")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(4, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "How did Voice members help/influence your project?")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(5, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Project/Study Outcomes/Findings")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(6, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "What will happen next with your research?")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(7, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Have any papers or reports been published as a result of the research project?")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(8, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "If yes, please upload a copy here")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(9, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "Photo to be displayed on the Voice website with your feedback. If possible, please attach a relevant photo from the project/study i.e. a picture of the research team, equipment etc, or the project/study logo.")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(10, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                else if (cap == "If further project information is available, please provide the link below")
                {
                    extractedCaptions.Remove(cap);
                    extractedCaptions.Insert(11, cap);
                    var keyOld = extractedFields[count].Key;
                    var valueOld = extractedFields[count].Value;
                    newOrderFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOld, valueOld));
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p>This opportunity has not received any feedback yet.</p>
        }

        <p><strong>Feedback form URL:&nbsp;</strong><a href="@feedbackFormUrl" target="_blank">@feedbackFormUrl</a></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Any code that does an exact match for a super-specific string like this, that is apparently intended for human consumption only, is at the very least suspect. This is extremely brittle -- even if it did work, literally any change in the wording would break it. What's the broader context of the problem it's intended to solve?

Comment: Could be a difference in whitespace (tabs, spaces, linefeeds). In HTML, any number of whitespace characters in a sequence are shown as one space in the browser, which could make you believe the source string has just that one space instead of what it really contains.

Comment: Problem I'm having is that we have users complete forms, after submission they are in a totally different arbitrary order each time. I'm trying to write logic to get them in the right order. Only way I can see to do it (different order every form) is to look for the specific string and then move it to where it needs to be.

Comment: Could this work instead: `else if (cap.StartsWith("Photo to be")) { ... }`- a little less brittle...

Comment: YES @PeterB! It has picked that up. I wasn't aware of `StartsWith` (new to C#) - thank you!

Comment: IMHO, instead of trying to match strings (extremely brittle for user provided input), _if you can_ add structured markup and extract the "innerText" it would probably make your life easier. If you've done some SEO you may have come across Google "micro data" - essentially adding `structured data` to HTML markup for Google crawler (instead of having it "figure out" what the page is about, markup "tells" it). TLDR; `<span itemprop="name">Elizabeth</span>`